# Eclipse unit test - one project per file/class?

Tags: unit-testing, gtest

My new company has never had unit testing, but have finally been persuaded to introduce it.

They have chosen Google test and, for some reason, want to run the unit tests from within Eclipse (where I, personally, would run it from the command line, preferably as some sort of CI and/or check-in process).

With hundreds, possibly thousands, of individual source files, each dealing with one class or a group of related functions, we need to have one test script per source file, but do we really need one Eclipse project, or can we just have as single, humungous project which runs each of the test scripts?

Management insist that the unit tests be runnable from within Eclipse.

Comment: You can run tests both from within eclipse and command-line.

Comment: Yup, that's my plan (+1). Ideally, I want to be able to test each file individually, but that seems like a lot of Eclipse projects to create.

Comment: You should create a test class for every source class you have, so you could run only the tests for that class if you want (while developing), but put all classes (source and tests) inside the same eclipse project

Comment: Look for example at the [elasticsearch github repo](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/core/src) where inside the `src` directory they have `main` and `test`.

Answer (score 2):

Usally Unit-Tests are included in the Project, typically under a different source-folder e.g.

`src` ==> for your Code
`test` ==> for your Unit-Tests.

If you use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html), you will get a structure similar to that.

Those tests can be run per Command line and from Eclipse ot-of-the-box, if the Tests are JUnit-Tests. Eclipse has a nice GUI for that, afaik its included in every Eclipse: [Eclise & Junit](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm)

Sometimes, people put their Tests in a seperate Project, so for each Eclipse-Project you have you create a _test-Project for the Unit-Tests. This might be an advantage, when you run the Tests seperate from you build, e.g. every 3 hours or so.

It is very uncommon to make one Project for each Class - you'll end easily up with thousands of Test-Projects.

For how to use Google-Test with Eclipse this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951808/using-googletest-in-eclipse-how